# php mysqli fetch_row only returns column name

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table with columns (user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pw) and 2 rows

1 admin admin@admin.com admin

2 user_1 user_1@user.com user_1

I am trying to query the db from PHP following this example
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

but when I print the output, I only get the column names instead of the values (and unfortunately, also line breaks get ignored)

Connection successfulSelect returned 2 rows.user_id, user_name, user_email user_id, user_name, user_email

I basically copied the example in the link. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php

$conn_error = "Could not connect to db";

$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_password = '';
$mysql_db = 'test';

$mysqli = new mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else {
  echo "Connection successful";
  }

$query = "SELECT 'user_id', 'user_name', 'user_email' FROM users";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    printf("Select returned %d rows.", mysqli_num_rows($result));

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf ("%s, %s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
    }

    $result->close();

} else {

    echo "Nothing returned on query " .$query;

}
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` inside the while loop give you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the field names. Change:

```sql
SELECT 'user_id', 'user_name', 'user_email' FROM users
```

To:

```sql
SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email FROM users
```

You probably intended to use back ticks, like this:

```sql
SELECT `user_id`, `user_name`, `user_email` FROM users
```

That would work as well, but they are only needed when you use reserved words or special characters (like spaces) in field names.